# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm a complete newby to JS. Trying to use SharePoint REST API to display a link list in a footer. Keep getting this error no matter what I do. It is for this line `LoadFooterLinks(results.d.results);`

```
function GetFooterLinks() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Footer Links')/items/?$orderby=Display_x0020_on_x0020_Homepage";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (results) {
            LoadFooterLinks(results.d.results);

        },
        error: function (error) {
              console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the value of results ? Try adding `console.log(results)` before your failing line and post the output

Comment: You say you keep getting an error now matter what you do ==> What error?  show us.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. How do you know you have an "error"?
2. Is is a Javascript **`Exception`**?
3. WHAT IS the error or **`Exception`**?
4. How do you know the error isn't with your `LoadFooterLinks()` function?
5. Most likely your results are NOT what you are expecting.  You're obviously:

   1. Successfully making a connection and request
   2. But, you can't be sure what's coming back.  It could be:

      1. empty string
      2. null
      3. malformed
6. Hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers will bring up that browser's Developer mode/built-in **JS console**
7. My code changes below should help you debug by outputting to the **console** for you.

---

#### Things to NOTE about the code changes:

1. The difference between:

   - catching a JavaScript **runtime exception/error** using `try-catch`  ***vs.***
   - outputting the **string** ***variable*** arbitrarily named **`"error"`** in the `failure` callback method of the `$.ajax` **object**
2. Print an exception to to the console doesn't require `console.err()`
3. If you want to show a **string** as an **error** in the **console** use `console.err()`, not `console.log`.
4. **`Null`** is an **object**, not a *datatype* or *primitive* like the other ones in JavaScript.  For Example,

   - boolean
   - string
   - undefined
   - number

---

## New Code

```
function GetFooterLinks() {
  var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +  
    "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Footer Links')/items/?  
    $orderby=Display_x0020_on_x0020_Homepage"
  ;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (results) {
        if (!results) { // should handle null and empty strings
          try{
            LoadFooterLinks(results.d.results);
          }
          catch (e){ // catch any JavaScript runtime exception (error)
            console.log(e); // print the error to the console 
                            // (hit F12 in most browsers to see 
                            // the console BEFORE you refresh 
                            // the page to run your code)
          }
        }
        else { 
          var msg = "The 'results' variable is ";
          var varType = typeof(results);
          if (varType == "object") {
            msg += "NULL";
          } 
          else {
            msg += varType;
          }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {  
      // this 'error' variable can be named
      // anything you'd like and is a string 
      // description of the AJAX error.  
      // This description comes from $.ajax - 
      // which is part of jQuery (a JS library).
      // This "error" is not a native JS 
      // exception; therefore, you wouldn't 
      // use a TRY-CATCH.  Also, since it's 
      // only a string, if you want to show it 
      // as an error in the console, you should 
      // use `console.err`, not `console.log`.
      console.err("Error in getting List: (0)", error); 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically doing is making a request to the "/_api/lists/getbytitle" method. 
When that method returns a response, it will do so as an object named "results", as you can see under the "success" callback.

What you are doing afterwards is reading a property called "d" and within "d" you are trying to obtain the value of property called "results".

What the error is saying is that "d" is undefined therefore it cannot retrieve the value of "results" from "d".

I suggest you check what is inside the object "results" of the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint API result, you would need to parse the JSON response to convert it to Javascript object. I've modified your code a bit to make it work in this case.

```
function GetFooterLinks() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Footer Links')/items/?$orderby=Display_x0020_on_x0020_Homepage";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var svcData = JSON.parse(response.data).d.results;
            LoadFooterLinks(svcData);

        },
        error: function (error) {
              console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName); 
        }
    });
}
```